# How to share data between actions in single Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

So I have this:

```
    public ActionResult ViewForum(int ForumID)
    {
        _frmSrv = new ForumService();
        _roleSrv = new RoleService();
        //_userAccess = new UserAccess();
        var modelView = _frmSrv.GetForumIndexView(ForumID);
        TempData[CurrentUser.Name] = _roleSrv.GetUserAccessForForum(CurrentUser, ForumID);
        modelView.UserAccess = TempData[CurrentUser.Name] as UserAccess;
        return View(modelView);
    }
```

and this:

```
    public ActionResult ViewThread(int ThreadID)
    {
        _postSrv = new PostService();
        var modelView = _postSrv.GetThreadIndexView(ThreadID);
        modelView.UserAccess = TempData[CurrentUser.Name] as UserAccess;
        return View(modelView);
    }
```

You probaly already guess I want to pass UserAccess from one action to another.
Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Why do you want to pass it? Is it for authentication and authorization? If so, then the model for this is well described in the docs and on blogs.

Comment: UserAccess is for checking if user role, have and specific permissions on forum, like read, post and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions in ASP.NET MVC are stateless which means that actions need to be passed all the information it needs for every request. You can do the following:

```
public ActionResult ViewThread(int ThreadID, int ForumID)
{
    _postSrv = new PostService();
    var modelView = _postSrv.GetThreadIndexView(ThreadID);
    modelView.UserAccess = _roleSrv.GetUserAccessForForum(CurrentUser, ForumID) as UserAccess;
    return View(modelView);
}
```

If it's possible to get the ForumID with only the ThreadID you don't need to change the method signature.

Comment: Yeah I did it this way later, but I wanted to avoid it.
One way or another I think there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

asp.net mvc is still asp.net, you can use sessions, cookies etc to do this